# java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException when using URLConnection

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, urlconnection, fedora-25

I'm trying to create a Telegram bot and my code already works, but suddenly I can't start my program, as it crashes with the following error. I did not change any code or do anything.

Perhaps this is a bug of the operating system?

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at test.main(test.java:10)
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:147)
    at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$Delegate.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:703)
    at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.<init>(ECDHCrypt.java:77)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverKeyExchange(ClientHandshaker.java:721)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:281)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:128)
    ... 14 more
```

Sometimes the code results in a segmentation fault:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f2b1fb65711, pid=3982, tid=0x00007f2b2081f700
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_111-b16) (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b16 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x14f711]  __memmove_avx_unaligned_erms+0x211
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core   dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid3982.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Aborted (luotiin core-tiedosto)
```

Minimal code to reproduce the error:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, MalformedURLException {
        URL url = new URL("https://api.telegram.org/bot<ID>/getUpdates?offset=0");
        URLConnection c = url.openConnection();
        c.connect();
    }
}
```

I'm running the code on Fedora 25 and OpenJDK.

```
$ uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.9.5-200.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 20 12:24:16 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Appears to be caused by a recent NSS update on Fedora, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1415137

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your version of NSS libraries, nss 3.28 seems to break stuff for java. It happens on gentoo too: https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=605430

Downgrading to nss 3.27.x fixed it for me and others as well.